# FancyBox Jquery Null Error - Strange issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I am experiencing a very strange issue i am hoping someone can answer (its kind of broad, but i will explain it my best), code works on local page when opened, but as soon as the same page is uploaded it throws an error. Two others have also looked at this, resulting in more confusion.

I downloaded FancyBox to use the inline feature to pop up a user form via href link, instead of taking the user to an additional page.

You can see the "stock" fancy box here:

**1** fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo
Under various options, Inline is what i am using.

I didnt need all of the other features that came with FancyBox so i stripped the page to the following, which works just fine:

**2** **[Fancy Box Demo Stripped to Inline Feature only](http://protimeshareresales.com/sandbox/PTR_delete/)**

So then, i applied this code to our sandbox copy of the page to implement:

**3** **[Sandbox Copy with Fancy Box inline feature added to "make offer" link](http://protimeshareresales.com/sandbox/PTR_resort/#inline1)**

It stops working! There are no conflicts with other javascript on the page, and the only difference is that it has a couple of color .css changes, all .fancybox was named to .ptroffer and that the css code is not inline on the page (which wouldn't cause this error anyway). 
This same page, opened locally works beautifully - upload and it throws error.
**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'ptroffer': object is null or undefined**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ptroffer').ptroffer();
    });
</script>
```

- Works fine with link #2, and with link #3 locally, but with #3 uploaded it throws error.

Please!

Comment: you are using prototype framework, are you using jQuery.noConflict? ... or change the alias `$` by `jQuery` in your custom script `jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery('.ptroffer').ptroffer();});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in your code somewhere is overriding `$`.  If you change that "ready" handler to call

```
jQuery('.ptroffer').ptroffer();
```

you won't get that error.  However, things may not work; I *think* that an older version of jQuery is being imported by something (1.3!), which is bad.

*edit* oh I see, something's pulling in Prototype.  You've got a regular script soup going on there, and things are going to be unpredictable and bizarre until you get that straightened out.  Probably somewhere in there something's calling `jQuery.noConflict()`, but that "ready" handler you're adding isn't written to expect that.  Whatever code that's expecting jQuery 1.3 may be in for a surprise also.

Comment: using the jQuery('.ptroffer').ptroffer(); instead, Fixed it! Thank you very much.